# Help identifying enlarger

Tags: printing, darkroom, enlarging

I walked past this incomplete negative enlarger [see images below] at a yard sale, and I impulsively picked it up for next to nothing. I would appreciate if anyone could help identify the model, and if possible what I would need to get it working.

Some observations:

- The enlarger body itself has no markings that I can find. Some image Googling seem to suggest the make to be a *Durst*. Based on the size of the opening over the lens, 36mm, I'm guessing that the enlarger is for 135 film only, no medium format. Any ideas on the model?
- It comes with a detachable EL-Nikkor 50 mm, f/4 lens.
- It lacks the enlarger head. (I think that's the name for the piece that should go on top of the lens and hold the negative.) Do I need a very specific head, or will multiple different Durst heads work?
- It's missing its base plate. If in a pinch, I could try to make one myself.

[image: Full side view]

[image: Front view, missing head]

[image: Top view, the square hole to the lens is just under 36 mm wide.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Durst M300 35mm Black&White enlarger.
Parts missing include- 1) Condenser box. 2) Film Negative holder. 3) Baseboard with pole bracket.
It will not be prudent to spend money on finding parts. If you want an enlarger that works- look further.
The parts you do have could be very useful- The lens might make a great copy lens (if you can find adapters for a camera mount). The Column with height winder makes a great copy stand- you would need a baseboard and bracket for the column.
http://www.jollinger.com/photo/cam-coll/manuals/enlargers/durst/Durst_M300.pdf